# Building jar using intellij idea (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, jar

**hey everyone **

**the story :**
update the jar file created using the shaded maven  plugin works as intended the issue i faced lies in the opencv library i use it for webcam operations and when the jar is deployed it cannot locate the dll file is there a way to include the dll file in the jar ?   .

**this is the plugin :**

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>Main_panel.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

**this is the code where the issue occurs : **

```
 System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        VideoCapture  capture=new VideoCapture(0);
```

i hope i get some help soon , thank you so much for your patience  .

Comment: I've never used Maven with javafx before but just got myself a javafx archetype and made a runnable jar with that and Shade. I can post it as an answer if you like. You probably would need only minimal changes to some ids in the pom

Comment: @g00se hello so i have an update it seems that the issue was with opencv library it cannot locate the dll when the jar is deployed , i'll make sure to update the post

Comment: *is there a way to include the dll file in the jar ? .* In a word, no. The library has to be in the file system. You might be better off using `jlink` + `jpackage` to do all this

Comment: @g00se is there a tutorial that specifically does this? or something similar to it?

Comment: [This](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/111-making-native-installable-apps-with-java-9) touches on it, but you might find something JavaFX-specific if you're lucky

Comment: See also the [tag:javafx] section on [_Packaging_](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info)

Comment: JavaFX packages the JavaFX native libraries into jmods (which are built to handle both native and Java code), or (for the JavaFX maven artifacts) by including the native libraries in the artifact jars and then extracting them at runtime to [a local cache directory from which it then loads them](https://github.com/Glavo/jfx/blob/c1f6c995a0445d75f0a715e598437460026f4e45/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/glass/utils/NativeLibLoader.java#L116).  That doesn't directly solve your problem with opencv, I just note how a similar problem was solved by a framework you use.

Comment: Related: [Running Executable Jar throws no opencv_java310 in java.library.path error but runs fine in IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962216/running-executable-jar-throws-no-opencv-java310-in-java-library-path-error-but-r) and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing)

Comment: *Anywhere you use System.getProperty("user.dir") it refers your app root folder.* That is simply *wrong*. It refers to the [current directory](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/91-find-the-current-directory-in-java) (where your app has been run from) which *could* be entirely different

Comment: @g00se you might want to comment on the answer to the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962216/running-executable-jar-throws-no-opencv-java310-in-java-library-path-error-but-r), to place the comment in context.